# Windows Media Service Plugin

Tags: windows, plugins, service, media

I have been trying to figure out quickly about writing a windows media service custom plugin.

My requirement is that I need to create a plugin which can authenticate users from database when they try to play a wmv file.Also they will have a time limit stored in database so they can play video for that amount of time only.

Even if I can get some idea of this can be achieved or how exactly can be proceeded will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me about 5 minutes to find the following documentation:

[Creating Authentication Plug-ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd892746.aspx)

From there you can find any documentation you need.

Comment: I already have this document and did went through it and configured it too.Although it doesn't show any way to interact with the database.